# Why each nonempty weakly open set of an infinite dimensional normed linear space is unbounded with respect to the norm

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces

Suppose $V$ is an infinite dimensional vector space, $f_i$ ($i$ is from $1$ to $n$) are real-valued linear functions on $V$, I cannot understand why the intersection of 
kernels of  $f_i$ must contain a nonzero element. If this question can be answered, then
it is easy to settle my problem. Thanks.

Comment: The co-dimension of a non-trivial linear functional is $1$. See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/330948/why-the-nontrivial-nullspace-of-a-linear-has-codimension-1).

Comment: Of the kernel, that is.

Comment: I got it. Thank you for your kind help.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that the intersection of the kernels contains only the zero vector. 
Consider $n+1$ vectors $v_1,\ldots, v_{n+1}$. We can pose the homogenous linear system 
$$
f_j(v_1)c_1+\cdots+f_j (v_{n+1})c_{n+1}=0, \ j=1,\ldots,n
$$
of $n$ equations in the $n+1$ variables $c_1,\ldots c_{n+1}$. This system has a nontrivial solution and so
$$
f_j(c_1v_1+\cdots+c_{n+1}v_{n+1})=0, \ j=1,\ldots,n,
$$
which implies that $c_1v_1+\cdots+c_{n+1}v_{n+1}$ is in the intersection of the kernels.  So $c_1v_1+\cdots+c_{n+1}v_{n+1}=0$, showing that $v_1,\ldots,v_{n+1}$ are linearly dependent.  Thus, $\dim V\leq n$.