# Clarification for a question in functional analysis

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-explanation

[Why the nontrivial nullspace of a linear has codimension 1?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/330948/why-the-nontrivial-nullspace-of-a-linear-has-codimension-1)

The answer that was top voted I understood for the most part, but at some point the author says that $f(y-\frac{f(y)}{f(x_0)}x_0)=0$. I understand that $f(0)=0$, I just am not sure why the author is able to assume that $y=\frac{f(y)}{f(x_0)}x_0$.

Edit: It has been pointed out that $y=\frac{f(y)}{f(x_0)}x_0$ is not necessarily true, and that $y-\frac{f(y)}{f(x_0)}x_0\in\ker f$. I guess this would be the better question for me to ask here, since I am not sure why this is able to be assumed.

Comment: You can have $f(x) = 0$ and $x \neq 0$ at the same time.

Comment: That's true. But $f(0)=0$, and I was unsure why someone is able to assume that $y-\frac{f(y)}{f(x_0)}x_0\in\ker f$, unless they were implying that to be true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $f$ is linear, we have

$$f\left(y- \frac{f(y)}{f(x_0)}x_0\right) = f(y) - \frac{f(y)}{f(x_0)}f(x_0) = f(y)-f(y) = 0$$
hence $y- \frac{f(y)}{f(x_0)}\in \ker f.$

Answer (score 1):

Let $V$ be a vector space and $f$ be a nonzero linear functional on $V$ over a field $\mathbb{F}$.  Clearly, $f$ is onto.  By the first isomorphism theorem, you have
$${V\over \ker(f)} \simeq \mathbb{F}$$
via the mapping $x + \ker(f) \mapsto f(x).$  We conclude that the codimension of
$\ker(f)$ is 1.